# Choose necessary JDK for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, homebrew

I have a lot of JDK versions installed by `Homebrew`

I check it with command `jenv versions`

[image]

But when I open IntelliJ Idea settings, I see only one JDK
[image]

What should I do if I want to choose all of the possible JDK's installed on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has only JDK's which are installed by the IDE, so if you want to see them all you must add them externally. Here is a link which can help - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-project-sdk.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ doesn't scan your hard drive for JDKs, so you need to "register" every JDK you want to use.

Go to File -> Project Structure -> SDKs, and then click the "+" icon above the list of SDKs. Choose "Add JDK" and then navigate it to the location the JDK you want to use is installed:

[image]

Comment: Intellij *does* scan your hard drive, and it's shown in the picture.

Comment: @NakarukatoshiUzumaki those are the files in a JDK I already have added

Comment: Oh, really? My fault, I thought that were detected by the IDE because of the "Detected" label HAHAHA. Thanks for clarifying it!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround here, as this is pretty convoluted.

You seem to be trying to set up a specific JRE to run Maven.

The list of available JDKs/JREs is the same as the one available in your project-specific settings.

You can open those by pressing F12 when highlighting the root folder (or any folder) in your project in the file tree on the left panel.

From there, you should see a modal that lists, among other things, a "Platform settings -> SDKs" menu.

Finally, you can add your local JDKs (and therefore JREs) based on their location in your file system.

[image]

Finally, go back to your maven settings and pick the correct one from the list.